# Not receiving custom contact form messages in BigCommerce

Tags: email, contact-form, bigcommerce

We just realized yesterday that we hadn't been receiving messages from our contact form on our contact page since the middle of April... Everything looks as if we would receive it (form resets after submit button is clicked and a success message displays), but we never receive the message on our end.

We wanted a 2 column layout, so we copied the html markup that's generated from the default form on BigCommerce, enabled recaptcha, and added JS for form validation.

Here's the first line of the form, which seems like it would work according to BigCommerce Docs:

```
<form data-contact-form class="form" id="contact-form" action="/pages.php?action=sendContactForm" method="post">
```

Here's the URL to the page:

www.thedashcamstore.com/contact-us

Answer (score 0):

The built-in contact form relies on the page type "Allow people to send questions/comments via a contact form." This instructs the BigCommerce app to send an email using the back-end infrastructure and by replacing it the instruction isn't sent. You can use third-party forms to modify how these pages are displayed without more customization and I've included some examples below:

[Jotform](https://jotform.com/)

[Wufoo](https://www.wufoo.com/)

[EmailMeForm](https://www.emailmeform.com/)

[Kontactr](https://kontactr.com/)